# RSS Feeds into Joomla

Tags: joomla, rss

Is there any way to get **RSS** feed into Joomla on an "**auto**" mode?

Meaning , each time the feed is updated ,a new article/content is created at Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Should have a look on the extensions directory. There are a few solutions:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/automatic-articles

Rss2Content, rssfactorypro and more.